# como hacer un container con un div en la esquina superior derecha

Tags: css, html5, css-grid-layout

Estoy intentando hacer esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

básicamente quiero poner 1 icono en cada círculo para editar y borrar y adentro del container pongo una imagen y texto como se ve en la imagen, sé que puede ser algo sencillo, pero no he podido sé que debe ser con un container general que incluya los 2 container hijos, pero cuando lo hago se ve mal y no logra este efecto adjunto código:

```html
   <div
  style="    display: flex;
width: auto;
margin: 14px;
box-shadow: 0 0 16px 8px #b3b3b440;
border-radius: 10px;"
>
  <div>
    <div
      style="
background: #F8F8F8;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 15px;
"
    >
      <img
        style="
width: 126px;
padding: 15px;
"
    src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dlqmpatgu/image/upload/v1618344092/580b585b2edbce24c47b2695_rxxkem.png"
      />
    </div>
    <div
      style="
margin: 6px;
margin-top: 45px;
">
      <span style="font-size:16px;   font-size: 18px;
     color: #16335e;
    font-weight: 500;">arreglo de flores rojas</span>
      <br/>
      <span
        style="margin-top: 5px;  font-size: 18px;
    color: #16335e;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;"
        >$ 109999 </span>
      <span
        style="margin-left:10px; font-size:14px; font-weight: 
  normal; color:#1FC94F"
        >Envío gratis</span>
      <br/>
      <span style="font-size:14px;  font-size: 18px;
  color: #16335e;
 font-weight: 500;"
        >2 Productos</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
       logo bonito
      </div>
      <div>
       logo bonito
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

he estado con esto 4 días cualquier ayuda es agradecida :)

también adjunto el código base que tenía antes en este solo está el div del container general y allí hago el flex para acomodar la imagen y el texto como en la imagen también mantengo un width automático para que se adapte depende del contenido del texto:

```html
    <div
  style="    display: flex;
   width: auto;
  margin: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 8px #b3b3b440;
  border-radius: 10px;">
  <div
    style="
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 15px;">
    <img
      style="
width: 126px;
padding: 15px;"
  src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dlqmpatgu/image/upload/v1618344092/580b585b2edbce24c47b2695_rxxkem.png"
    />
  </div>
  <div
    style="
margin: 6px;
margin-top: 45px;"
  >
    <span style="font-size:16px;  font-size: 18px;
  color: #16335e;
  font-weight: 500;">flores 
  bonitas</span>
    <br/>
    <span
      style="margin-top: 5px;
   font-size: 18px;   font-size: 18px;
   color: #16335e;
   font-weight: 500;"
      >$ 109990</span>
    <span
      style="margin-left:10px; font-size:14px; font-weight: normal; 
  color:#1FC94F"
      >Envío gratis</span>
    <br/>
    <span style="font-size:14px;  font-size: 18px;
   color: #16335e;
   font-weight: 500;"
      >2 Productos</span
    >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para que pueda _ejecutarse_ el código en el navegador (usando un snippet). Al hacerlo, veo que tu código incluye cosas que no son css y html, es mejor que publiques un [mcve].

Comment: Listo realizada gracia por la corrección

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes probar es poniendole al contenedor principal, position relative y dentro de este poner los dos divs que contendran los iconos, a estos dos ponerles position absolute para ubicarlos donde desees, te dejo mi prueba para que lo repliques.

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            height: 100vh;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .card {
            width: 400px;
            height: 250px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 30px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
            position: relative;
        }
        .icons {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #fff;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 50px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        }

        .add {
            right: 65px;
            top: -25px;
        }

        .delete {
            right: 0;
            top: -25px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card">
    holaa
    <div class="icons add">+</div>
    <div class="icons delete">-</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

El position absolute lo ubicara arriba del contenedor y el right lo ubicara a la derecha, ya ahi puedes acomodarlo

```html
    <div
  style="    display: flex;
   width: auto;
  margin: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 8px #b3b3b440;
  border-radius: 10px;">
  <div
    style="
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 15px;">
<div style="position: absolute;right: 0; top: 0; margin: 25px;background-color: red;color: #f8f8f8;padding: 5px; border-radius: 50%;">
    X
</div>
    <img
      style="
width: 126px;
padding: 15px;"
  src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dlqmpatgu/image/upload/v1618344092/580b585b2edbce24c47b2695_rxxkem.png"
    />
  </div>
  <div
    style="
margin: 6px;
margin-top: 45px;"
  >
    <span style="font-size:16px;  font-size: 18px;
  color: #16335e;
  font-weight: 500;">flores 
  bonitas</span>
    <br/>
    <span
      style="margin-top: 5px;
   font-size: 18px;   font-size: 18px;
   color: #16335e;
   font-weight: 500;"
      >$ 109990</span>
    <span
      style="margin-left:10px; font-size:14px; font-weight: normal; 
  color:#1FC94F"
      >Envío gratis</span>
    <br/>
    <span style="font-size:14px;  font-size: 18px;
   color: #16335e;
   font-weight: 500;"
      >2 Productos</span
    >
  </div>
</div>
```